# JqueryUI DatePicker parseDate comparison

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to compare a date in the jqueryui datepicker.beforeShowDay() to establish whether a day is selectable or not. However it doesn't seem to work. The code is:

```
function (d) {
    if ((d.getDay() == 0) || (d == $.datepicker.parseDate('yy/mm/dd', '2012/12/25'))) {
      return [false, ""];
    }
    else {
      return [true, "2"]
    };
}
```

the first test (getDay) works fine but the second does not:

```
(d == $.datepicker.parseDate('yy/mm/dd', '2012/12/25')): false
```

even though

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', '25/12/2012'): Tue Dec 25 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

and

```
d: Tue Dec 25 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

which look the same to me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `formatDate` method to get it to the string format first then do a comparison of the same type:

```
function (d) {
    var datestrInNewFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy/mm/dd", d);
    if ((d.getDay() == 0) || (datestrInNewFormat == '2012/12/25')) {
      return [false, ""];
    }
    else {
      return [true, "2"]
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2j3c3/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to compare `object` with `string`.
On first test, you used `d.getDay()` that is method of Date object in javascript.

try to convert your `d` object into string.

Comment: not quite the correct answer but put me on the path. the parseDate() does return a date. The fix that worked was d.toDateString() == $.datepicker.parseDate('yy/mm/dd', '2012/12/25').toDateString()